# Is there any service to rent cloud CPU power to increase my mac power?

Tags: software-recommendation, cpu

I'd like to know if there is any service to easily rent CPU power on OSX to speed up my mac. It would be really nice to be able to do something like [this](https://shadow.tech/), but with OSX.

Is there such a service?

Comment: Do you want this additional cpu time for calculations?  or just general speed up of your mac?

Comment: Just CPU for calculation for the moment ;)

Comment: There is always AWS. Not macOS of course, but calculations may not need a specific OS

Comment: I don't think this can really work the way you're thinking of. Even the best network connections have too much latency for an "extra, remote CPU core" to be useful for general purpose stuff. Even over LAN, I don't think it would be feasible. There's a reason external GPUs need thunderbolt.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that it could be a bit ambitious, but damn this would be truly awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ever used them, but [Macminicolo](https://macminicolo.net) might be of interest to you. It won't speed up your *subjective* Mac user experience, but it can provide computational and server-related services that you can offload.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!
It's interesting but a little expensive compared to my original needs. I'd really like to have access to a remote CPU and just use it, seems like it doesn't exist :/