# Is there any way to stream my Mac Pro to my MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, virtualization

I'd like to know if there is an efficient way to use my Mac Pro from my MacBook (Not using anything like TeamViewer or VNC), so I can enjoy the power of the Mac Pro with the mobility of the MacBook while I'm home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I regularly use VNC and ssh to my Mac Pro from my MacBook all the time to do things my mobile CPU doesn’t thrive on. This is very efficient for me, so I’m not sure what is lacking in your setup. Run server apps and calculation and Xcode builds on your MacPro and let your MacBook do the things it is suited.

- screens app is great for remote screen viewing
- prompt app is great for ssh from iOS

I have App Store caching service on the MacPro and iCloud caching and run longer compiles remotely and anything I can script and batch as well.

When that’s not enough, run things in Azure, AWS, google compute or a Mac hosted service, no?

- [Is there any service to rent cloud CPU power to increase my mac power?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303732/is-there-any-service-to-rent-cloud-cpu-power-to-increase-my-mac-power)